# How to add tabs pages on different pages in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i have checked various other question related to this but non was answered, So I am writing back this.

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="ios-add"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="ios-alarm"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabIcon="ios-albums"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabIcon="ios-alert"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tabs.ts**

```
// all imports are done.

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

tab1Root = AlarmPage;
tab2Root = AddPage;
tab3Root = AlbumsPage;
tab4Root = AlertPage;

constructor() {

}
```

**alert-page.ts**

```
//all imports are made
// syntaxes are done correctly

export class AlertPage {
    constructor(navCtrl: NavController){}

 gotToOtherPage(){

    this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage);
}
```

}

**other-page.ts**

```
//When I navigate to other page from the above mentioned pages the tabs does not displayed on the OtherPage.
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of following function to navigate to tabs page

```
gotToOtherPage(){

    this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage);
}
```

Just remover it. This code work fine. But you have to include your added page in app.module.ts also

I have done a sample project for you here is the link:
[TabsPage](https://github.com/Razztha/TestTabPage)

Here I have added a page called detail page. Check this out